# Converting dicom file raising an OSError: cannot write mode I;16 as JPEG

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pydicom

I am trying to convert a Computed Radiography dicom file to jpeg using the code below but its raising an OSError: cannot write mode I;16 as JPEG. Here is the code I am using to convert:

```
    ds = read_file('Dicom_files/' + dicomname)
    im = fromarray(ds.pixel_array)
    im.save('./Jpeg/' + dicomname + '.jpg')
```

It's raising the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wisdom/Desktop/DCM_OUPUT_WRITING/info2.py", line 118, in <module>
    img = take_dicom(i)
  File "/home/wisdom/Desktop/DCM_OUPUT_WRITING/info2.py", line 28, in take_dicom
    final_img = im.save('./Jpeg/' + dicomname + '.jpg')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2240, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 631, in _save
    raise OSError(f"cannot write mode {im.mode} as JPEG") from e
OSError: cannot write mode I;16 as JPEG
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is you DICOM image in tif-format? DICOM is an image and all metadata about the patient. What is the image in?

Comment: The dicom is a ".dcm" file.

Answer (score 3):

Regular JPEG uses 8 bits per sample. If your data is 16-bit, you'll need to either:

- scale it down (thereby losing radiometric resolution) and use JPEG, or
- use a format that supports 16-bit such as PNG or TIFF.